# Complementary Filter Code Not functioning

Tags: numpy, python-2.7

I've been scratching my head too long.

The data is coming from an 3D accelerometer and 3D gyro. I am using a complementary filter to control drift.

I have it working in excel but can't seem to get this python code to do the same thing:

```
r1_angle_cfx = np.zeros(len(r1_angle_ax))
r1_angle_cfx[0] = r1_angle_ax[0]

for i in xrange(len(r1_angle_ax)-1):
        j = i + 1
        r1_angle_cfx[j] = 0.98 *(r1_angle_cfx[i] + r1_alpha_x[j]*fs) + (0.02 * r1_angle_ax[j])    #complementary filter
```

In excel (correct) I get:

[image: pic1]

In python (incorrect) I get:

[image: pic2]

What is going wrong? and is there a better way to do this in python?

Thanks,
Scott

EDIT: Link to data files - 
[sample data](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/408k5mgt5uzxkrt/AAConhbc8ZMJk_Ec2vgsa-5ta)
1. The csv file contains accelerometer, gyro data that is entered into the filter formula as well as those values that were calculated in excel.
2. The excel file contains all raw data (steps not mentioned above but I have triple checked and are equivalent up to the point of being entered in the filter formula).

EDIT 2: update - Turns out my code works. It was sloppy debugging. fs should be fs = 0.01. In my code I had fs = 1/100 which ends up = 0 in the script.

Comment: Can you give as a link to your sample data to try it?

Comment: Also, where is `fs` coming from?

Comment: I think you probably mean "complementary", not "complimentary".

Comment: Link now provided to sample data, above. fs is the 1/samplingfreq which is 1/100 which is dt (time between samples). And, yes, complementary. I guess I was hoping is would compliment my analysis.

Comment: Added Edit 2 as an update of where I went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Python code looks pretty reasonable.  Without example data, I can't do much more than say that.

But I can guess.  I looked up "complementary filters" and found a link explaining them:

https://sites.google.com/site/myimuestimationexperience/filters/complementary-filter

This link gives an example equation that is very similar to yours:

```
angle = (1-alpha)*(angle + gyro * dt) + (alpha)*(acc)
```

You have `fs` where this has `dt`, and `dt` is computed as `1/sampling_frequency`.  If `fs` is the sampling frequency, maybe you should try inverting it?

EDIT: Okay, now that you posted the data, I played around with this.  Here is my program that gets a correct result.

Your code looks basically correct, so I think you must have made a mistake in your code that collected the values.  I'm not quite sure because your variable names confuse me.

I used a `namedtuple` and for the names, I used the column headers from the CSV file (with spaces and periods removed to make a valid Python identifier).

```
import collections as coll
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import sys


fs = 100.0
dt = 1.0/fs
alpha = 0.02

Sample = coll.namedtuple("Sample",
    "accZ accY accX rotZ rotY rotX r acc_angZ acc_angY acc_angX cfZ cfY cfX")

def samples_from_file(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        next(f)  # discard header row
        csv_reader = csv.reader(f, dialect='excel')

        for i, row in enumerate(csv_reader, 1):
            try:
                values = [float(x) for x in row]
                yield Sample(*values)
            except Exception:
                lst = list(row)
                print("Bad line %d: len %d '%s'" % (i, len(lst), str(lst)))


samples = list(samples_from_file("data.csv"))

cfx = np.zeros(len(samples))

# Excel formula: =R12
cfx[0] = samples[0].acc_angX
# Excel formula: =0.98*(U12+N13*0.01)+0.02*R13
# Excel: U is cfX  N is rotX  R is acc_angX
for i, s in enumerate(samples[1:], 1):
    cfx[i] = (1.0 - alpha) * (cfx[i-1] + s.rotX*dt) + (alpha * s.acc_angX)

check_line = [s.cfX - cf for s, cf in zip(samples, cfx)]

plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(check_line)
plt.plot(cfx)
plt.show()
```

`check_line` is the difference between the saved `cfX` value from the CSV file, and the new computed `cfx` value.  As you can see in the plot, this is a straight line at 0, so my calculation is agreeing quite well with yours.

So I guess the mapping of names is:

```
your_name       my_name
________________________
r1_angle_cfx    cfx
r1_alpha_x      rotX
r1_angle_ax     acc_angX
```

Comment: Yes, fs is the 1/sampling frequency which is 1/100 in this case or 0.01. I'll get some data to share.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks again for the work. Your code gave me some new ideas. See my edit 2 for why my code did not work in the fist place.